# Animate generated tables cells when div container is partially visible on screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a code to generate tables of 0's and 1's within specific div containers across the page and they work simply fine. The new challenge I'm trying to achieve is to animate these 0's and 1's appended to this div containers whenever the div is partially visible on the screen, the idea is to flip the numbers for at least 1 sec? change them constantly until the second completes and leave the new number there. I have the trigger code to verify whenever this div is visible on screen but not sure how to update the created and appended cells with 0's and 1's to each independent div container.

```js
var min = 0;
var max = 1;

function drawTable(divElement, totalRows, cellsInRow) {
    // get the reference for the body
    var randomNumbers = document.querySelector(divElement);
    
    var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
      // isIntersecting is true when element and viewport are overlapping
      // isIntersecting is false when element and viewport don't overlap
      if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
    // for now I can render this on console log but how to animate the cells (0's and 1's) during a sec for that specific container or divElement?
        console.log(divElement + ' is visible now');
    }, { threshold: [0] });

observer.observe(document.querySelector(divElement));
    
    // creates a <table> element
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    tbl.style.width = '100%';
    tbl.style.height = '100%';

    // creating rows
    for (var r = 0; r < totalRows; r++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        // create cells in row
        for (var c = 0; c < cellsInRow; c++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        tbl.appendChild(row);
    }

    randomNumbers.appendChild(tbl);
}
window.onload = (event) => {
    drawTable(".randomNumbers2", 8, 8);
    drawTable(".randomNumbers3", 16, 16);
    drawTable(".randomNumbers4", 8, 8);
    drawTable(".randomNumbers5", 24, 24);
};
```

```css
.randomNumbers2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  }
  
.randomNumbers3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 900px;
  }
  
.randomNumbers4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1750px;
  }
  
.randomNumbers5 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2500px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="randomNumbers2"></div>
<div class="randomNumbers3"></div>
<div class="randomNumbers4"></div>
<div class="randomNumbers5"></div>
```

Comment: Possibly not relevant, but what does  row.style.width = tbl.width / totalRows; do as tbl.width doesn't seem to have been set and why would the width of a row depend on the total number of rows?

Comment: thanks @AHaworth that was an error, I was testing something :)! deleted!

Comment: Could you explain what 'change them constantly' for a second means? If it is to be visible to a human you probably don't mean changing them every millisecond, or even every frame.

Comment: probably change it around every 100ms or a 10th of a sec :) or 10 times within a second. @AHaworth

Comment: So is it a case of setting a timeout when it enters the viewport, and running through the setting code again, doing that 10 times?

Comment: right @AHaworth, not sure how to solve that yet.